# how to extract jenkins credentials to python script

Tags: python, jenkins

I am having a groovy script that uses some credentials from jenkins credentials like this:

```
stage('Download tokens') {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'jenkins-token', variable: 'token')])
```

I want something similar to this in python to retrive the token in order for passing it to a python module which needs the token to e authenticated. Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I got it work by doing this:

```
stage('Download tokens') {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'jenkins-token', variable: 'token')]) {

            sh "export token=${token}"

             sh """
                   export token="${token}"

                   python3 script.py
             """

        }
    }
```

and in the script itself I called the token I need like this:

```
vault_token = os.environ['token']
```