# Fetch Jenkins credentials from Python script

Tags: python, jenkins

Is there any way to fetch Jenkins credentials from Python script? I have gone through below link but that will not work in my case.

[how to extract jenkins credentials to python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71616996/how-to-extract-jenkins-credentials-to-python-script)

Tried below but not sure what to use in place of <folder_name> in get_credentials_info()

```
 import jenkins

 server = jenkins.Jenkins('http://localhost:8080', 
 username='<username>', password='<password>')
 user = server.get_whoami()
 version = server.get_version()
 print('Hello %s from Jenkins %s' % (user['fullName'], version))
 cred_value = 
 server.get_credential_info('<cred_id>','<folder_name>')

 print('Hello %s from', cred_value)
```

Comment: By "Jenkins credentials" you mean credentials stored in Jenkins, not credentials to access Jenkins, right? The example you linked is a bit convoluted, but generally that's how it's done - `withCredentials` in Jenkins and `os.environ` in python. Why wouldn't it work in your case?

Comment: The requirement is to implement withCredentials in Python

Comment: You could hit `/scriptText` [API endpoint](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-console/#remote-access), but you still need to get Jenkins API token from somewhere.